# Is it possible to log HTTP connections within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, http, networking

I'd like to develop an application that can listen for unencrypted sensitive information (info similar to the data leading to a class action filed against Storm8) across one or more iPhone/iThouch applications. I've been unable to find any info on whether or not this would be possible.

- Is it possible to log HTTP (including get/post and headers) data from an iPhone app?
- Is there a log that already exists containing this information?

Bonus:

- Would this be achievable in a "jailed" iPhone environment?

Thanks all

Comment: Maybe is your question about getting logs where connexion aren't launched from your app but from Safari and others app ? I think it's not possible for others app or Safari. With a "jailbreak", it should be possible (but I can't give you a clue ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible outside your own app

Comment: Well, thanks, that's too bad. Any idea if it's possible in a jailbroken environment?